# JsPsych What kind of unit tests are these? Javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jspsych

I'm working on an existing project but I am new to Javascript. The project can be found here, it is JsPsych and I've searched the documentation here and cannot find the answer (http://docs.jspsych.org/)

I don't understand how they are doing unit tests. I have found the "testing" folder and you can view it below, here.

[JsPsych test folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TdgY.png)

Here's an example called "load.test.js"

```
const root = '../';
require(root + 'jspsych.js');
require(root + 'plugins/jspsych-single-stim.js');

test('jsPsych should be in the window object', function(){
  expect(typeof window.jsPsych).not.toBe('undefined');
});
```

Does anyone recognize this type of unit test? Is this supposed to be paired with some software? Can someone explain how I would actually run this?

Comment: Judging from the syntax, it could be Ava. Check the package.json of the project and see what test framework is in the dependencies

Answer (score 1):

The tests are run with [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/). You can see that `jest` is called as the test command in [package.json](https://github.com/jodeleeuw/jsPsych/blob/master/package.json#L10).

To run the tests, [install node and npm](https://nodejs.org/en/) on your system. Then run `npm install` in the repository's main directory. Then you can run `npm test`.